# C++ Delete Duplicates function from a Singularly Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I wrote a function that takes in a singularly linked list and returns the list with duplicates removed. So for example, given a linked list [1,1,2,3,4,5], we want to return [1,2,3,4,5].

Here is the code:

```
 ListNode* deleteDuplicates(ListNode* head) {
        if(head == NULL){
            return NULL;
        }

        ListNode* temp1 = head; 
        ListNode* temp2 = head->next; 

        while(temp2 != NULL){
            if (temp1->val != temp2-> val){
                temp1->next = temp2; 
                temp1 = temp1->next; 
            }
            temp2 = temp2->next;
           
        }
        temp1->next = NULL;
       
       return head;
}
```

Important thing to note is I was able to get this function to work properly through some trial and error but I don't actually understand how everything works.

I'm confused with the return part of the function: return head;
It seems that there was no explicit line of code that updates head so I originally thought returning head would return the original input no matter what. So how in this function did head actually get updated?

Comment: Recommendation: first write a `removeNode` method that takes a pointer to the node to be deleted and then unlinks and deletes it. That's relatively easy to write and test. Once you have that, then `deleteDuplicates` only has to find duplicates and call `removeNode`. Plus this probably won't be the only time you have to remove a node, so why write the code over and over?

Comment: Give `temp1` and `temp1` descriptive names. See what happened there? I accidentally typed `temp1` twice. This can easily happen to you, and it's a <expletive deleted> to spot sometimes. Isn't it? Anyway, If you call them something like `current` and `next`, you describe their use and behaviour better, making it easier for people to read your code.

Comment: The best way to [grok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok) the linked list is to draw pictures. Draw every step of the transaction, every link and every unlink and every node `delete`ed, so that you can make sure everything remains connected or at least pointed at so that it can be reconnected or `delete`ed later. When you run into trouble, you step through the problem function with a debugger and draw exactly what the program did. Where that drawing diverges from your originals, there's the bug.

Comment: And yes, there is no way this function can change `head`, so there's not much point to returning anything. Unless you're also tracking a tail pointer.

Comment: @Michelle Liu It is unclear whether the function must remove adjacent duplicate elements or any duplicate elements. Another question is are nodes created dynamically? If so then you need to call the operator delete for removed nodes.

Comment: @Michelle Liu Actually the function does not make sense.

Comment: If you use your debugger to step through the shown code, one line by one line, the reason why `head` never needs to be updated should become very obvious.